# r - retrieve couple ID in household grid

Tags: r, loops

I am working with what is known as a `household grid` which is generally found in surveys. The `household grid` indicates the relationship between the members of an household.

I tried to reproduce one here

```
  houseID id    sex age relto1   relto2         relto3         relto4
1       1  1   male  45      0   spouse not applicable not applicable
2       1  2 female  38 spouse        0 not applicable not applicable
3       2  1 female  18      0 daughter       daughter not applicable
4       2  2   male  50 parent        0         spouse not applicable
5       2  3 female  45 parent   spouse              0 not applicable
6       3  1 female  45      0   parent         parent         spouse
7       3  2   male  17    son        0        brother            son
8       3  3   male  19    son  brother              0            son
9       3  4   male  50 spouse   parent         parent              0
```

`houseID` is the unique household identifier, `id` the unique id of membres of an household, `relto_` indicates the relationship to `id` for each household.

For instance, **row 1**, `relto2 == spouse` meaning that `id == 1` is the `spouse` of `id == 2` for the first household.

I am interested in retrieving the spouse identifier. 
The trick is that `spouse id` are not always at the same position.

In household number 4, spouses are in `id` 1 and 4.

What I am interested in is to do this

```
  houseID id    sex age spousenum
1       1  1   male  45         2
2       1  2 female  38         1
3       2  1 female  18         0
4       2  2   male  50         3
5       2  3 female  45         2
6       3  1 female  45         4
7       3  2   male  17         0
8       3  3   male  19         0
9       3  4   male  50         1
```

The best code I could come up to is this one

```
dtsp = df[, grepl('rel', colnames(df))  ] 

# not too long, its fine # 
for(i in 1:nrow(dtsp)){
  for(j in 1:ncol(dtsp)){
    if(dtsp[i, j] == 'spouse'){
      df[i,'spousenum'] <- j
    }
  }
}
```

However, it seems a bit dodgy and slow.

Any idea for a more efficient code ?

**The data**

```
df = rbind(c('1', '1', 'male', '45', '0', 'spouse', 'not applicable', 'not applicable'), 
        c('1', '2', 'female', '38', 'spouse', '0', 'not applicable', 'not applicable'), 
       c('2', '1', 'female', '18', '0', 'daughter', 'daughter', 'not applicable'), 
        c('2', '2', 'male', '50', 'parent', '0', 'spouse', 'not applicable'), 
        c('2', '3', 'female', '45', 'parent', 'spouse', '0', 'not applicable'), 
        c('3', '1', 'female', '45', '0', 'parent', 'parent', 'spouse'), 
        c('3', '2', 'male', '17', 'son', '0', 'brother', 'son'), 
        c('3', '3', 'male', '19', 'son', 'brother', '0', 'son'), 
        c('3', '4', 'male', '50', 'spouse', 'parent', 'parent', '0'))

df = as.data.frame(df)
colnames(df) = c('houseID', 'id', 'sex', 'age', 'relto1', 'relto2', 'relto3',  'relto4')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this easily with `max.col`.  Subset the 'relt' columns of dataset (using `grep`), create a logical matrix with `==`, use `max.col` to find the `first` index of TRUE value for each row, multiply with `rowSums` so that if there are no TRUE values, it becomes 0, and `cbind` with the non-relt columns of dataset.

```
i1 <- grep("relt", colnames(df1))
m1 <- df1[i1] == "spouse"
cbind(df1[-i1], spousenum = max.col(m1, "first")*rowSums(m1))
#    houseID id    sex age spousenum
#1       1  1   male  45         2
#2       1  2 female  38         1
#3       2  1 female  18         0
#4       2  2   male  50         3
#5       2  3 female  45         2
#6       3  1 female  45         4
#7       3  2   male  17         0
#8       3  3   male  19         0
#9       3  4   male  50         1
```

---

If we are interested in `dplyr/tidyr` family solutions, create a rowname column with `tibble::rownames_to_column`, reshape to 'long' format with `gather`, `filter` only the 'spouse' rows, `transmute` to convert to 'rn' column to `numeric`, extract the numeric part from 'relt' to create 'spousenum', use `complete` with `full_seq` (from `tidyr`) to create the full sequence of 'rn' while filling the 'spousenum' with 0, and cbind it with the original dataset.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
rownames_to_column(df1, var = "rn") %>%
          gather(relt, val, relto1:relto4) %>% 
          filter(val == "spouse") %>%
          transmute(rn = as.numeric(rn), spousenum = as.numeric(sub("\\D+", "", relt))) %>% 
          complete(rn = full_seq(rn, 1), fill = list(spousenum=0)) %>% 
          select(-rn) %>% 
          bind_cols(df1, .) %>%
          select(-matches("relt"))
#  houseID id    sex age spousenum
#1       1  1   male  45         2
#2       1  2 female  38         1
#3       2  1 female  18         0
#4       2  2   male  50         3
#5       2  3 female  45         2
#6       3  1 female  45         4
#7       3  2   male  17         0
#8       3  3   male  19         0
#9       3  4   male  50         1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df$spousenum = apply(df[,5:8], 1, function(r) which(r=='spouse')[1])
```